# Embedding Tokenization layer into Model

Tags: python

I have 2 models. How can I combine these 2 models? It's something like the example . But I can't reproduce it. I have put the code on the Colab.

- 2 Tokenization Model
- Trained model

Answer (score 1):

Use Functional API:

```
input = (
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32), 
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)
  )
x = model1(input)
x = model2(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
```

Comment: @h4nk use `model.predict()`

Comment: @h4nk I never open links. You should describe all the necessary information in your question